# Custom Alerts SharePoint 2010 (KB 948321)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, alert

I've been trying to create a custom alert for SharePoint 2010 using the following guidelines : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948321/en-us

At this point I haven't succeeded in getting the alert to work. I was wondering of this guide also applies for SharePoint 2010. Because at the button of the article is clearly states:

APPLIES TO

- Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007
- Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 for Search (Enterprise Edition)
- Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 for Search (Standard Edition)

Can anyone enlighten me?

Kind regards
Oxillery

Answer (score 3):

I have it working in 2010.

**A new Alert Template.**

a.Original is found here:

```
    \14\TEMPLATE\XML\alerttemplates.xml
```

b.The custom templates are found in this file which has the original definitions plus the custom definitions.

```
CCPersonalAlertTemplates.xml
```

c.Load them with stsadm

```
    stsadm.exe -o updatealerttemplates -url "http://Beefy.com/Sites/my_name" -filename " \CCPersonalAlertTemplates.xml"
```

d.Every out of the box solution has a matching custom template.

- The custom templates have a .ext at the end of their name.
- The custom features also call a custom NotificationHandlerAssembly like this:

  ```
   <Properties>
   <NotificationHandlerAssembly>Shared.CCPersonalEmail, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5694e116d3fc8c0c</NotificationHandlerAssembly>
   <NotificationHandlerClassName>Shared.CCPersonalEmail.CCPersonalClass
   </NotificationHandlerClassName> 
   <NotificationHandlerProperties />
   </Properties>
  ```

**Custom Notification Handler assembly**

a.IAlertNotifyHandler that implements an OnNotification method
  - Attempts to send the custom alert (if it fails send normal alert.)

- Custom alert:

  - Gets the PersonalEmail field data from the User Information List
  - If Personal Email is empty it just sends normal alert
  - If personal email is populated

    - Send normal email to internal email
    - Send reduced email to external address
    - Replace `http://` with external address `http://extranet-`
    - Regex replace (keep content data from being sent)

      `<td class=\"formlabel\">.*<td class=\"altvb\">&nbsp;</td>`

**Make all the alerts use the external template**

- Existing alerts:

  - Site.allwebs.alerts get flipped to the same template name they had with .ext appended
  - Future alerts:

    - Site.allwebs.lists flipped the attached alerttemplates to their .ext counterpart
  - Future webs and their Future lists

    - SPListEventReceiver ListAdded() event flips the template on all lists created in the site collection

**Housekeeping**

a.During feature activation

- create a PersonalEmail field on the rootweb’s User Information List (This becomes content so it is not removed upon deactivation)
- flip all lists and alerts to the custom alert templates.

  - During feature deactivation

    - Flip all lists and alerts back to their respective out of box alert templates

Comment: Hi, I'm trying out your example you posted on Sharepoint.Stackexchange but I get an Access Denied error in the call of "colSPAT.Add(newSPAT)" when activating the feature: AlertTemplatesEventReceiver. I've tried running it with Elevated Privileges but that didn't help. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: More thorough version with code is available here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76085/how-can-i-create-custom-alerts-for-external-email-addresses/76086#76086

Comment: Check your feature scope, then post ULS logs of the lines just before the Access denied error.